# wso2 private paas, about init.sh's launch-params

Tags: wso2, paas

We are trying to use wso2 private PaaS. In
one step, we need execute "`private-paas-cartridges/common/vm/init-scripts/ec2/centos/init.sh`". When it executes:

```
<${WGET} http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data -O /tmp/payload/launch-params>
```

it always returns "`404 not found`".

The 169.254.169.254 site isn't available sometimes (because we are in china); can we set parameters manually? Some launch-params, for example?

Comment: could you post more detailed examples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: 169.254.169.254 site isn't available anywhere. Address such this (called  APIPA) indicated a problem in your network stack.

Comment: Formatting, language tweaking

Comment: We follow the instruction here<https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP410/Deploying+PPaaS>.

Comment: We follow the instruction here [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP410/Deploying+PPaaS).  In here [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP410/Configuring+a+Base+Image), It require to execute init.sh, this script report 404 error. Please give me a sample about launch-parms.